# Writing Hard drive serial string to Binary file

Tags: c#, hex, streamwriter, serial-number

I have a simple function that grabs the hard drive serial number from the C:\ drive and puts it into a string:

```
ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"C:\"");
disk.Get();
string hdStr = Convert.ToString(disk["VolumeSerialNumber"]);
```

I'm then attempting to convert the string above into ASCII and then write it out to a binary file, the issue I'm having is, when converting this string and saving the file using streamwriter, and opening the file in a hex editor, I'm seeing more bytes that I originally wanted to write so for example "16342D1F4A61BC"

Will come out as: 08 16 34 2d 1f 4a 61 c2 bc

It's adding the 08 and c2 in there somehow...

The more complete version is as follows:

```
string constructor2 = "16342D1F4A61BC";
string StrValue = "";

while (constructor2.Length > 0)
{
    StrValue += System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(constructor2.Substring(0, 2), 16)).ToString();
    // Remove from the hex object the converted value
    constructor2 = constructor2.Substring(2, constructor2.Length - 2);
}

FileStream writeStream;
try
{
    writeStream = new FileStream(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\license.mgr", FileMode.Create);
    BinaryWriter writeBinay = new BinaryWriter(writeStream);
    writeBinay.Write(StrValue);
    writeBinay.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Can anyone help me understand how these are getting added in?

Comment: You can't just write the output directly?

Comment: What's the purpose of the while loop?  There's a handy Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string) that will return you the necessary bytes from any string.

Comment: I think you are saying that you want to see the hex representation of the harddrive id when you view your output file in hex.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string constructor2 = "16342D1F4A61BC";
File.WriteAllBytes("test.bin", ToBytesFromHexa(constructor2));
```

With the following helper routines:

```
public static byte[] ToBytesFromHexa(string text)
{
    if (text == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("text");

        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
    bool low = false;
    byte prev = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length ; i++)
    {
        byte b = GetHexaByte(text[i]);
        if (b == 0xFF)
            continue;

        if (low)
        {
            bytes.Add((byte)(prev * 16 + b));
        }
        else
        {
            prev = b;
        }
        low = !low;
    }
    return bytes.ToArray();
}

public static byte GetHexaByte(char c)
{
    if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
        return (byte)(c - '0');

    if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'F'))
        return (byte)(c - 'A' + 10);

    if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'f'))
        return (byte)(c - 'a' + 10);

    return 0xFF;
}
```

Comment: Simon! That did exactly what I wanted it to do, thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [System.Text.Encoding.ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx).GetBytes(hdStr) to get the bytes that represent the string in ASCII.

Comment: @tofutim, I can't write it directly I need to write the ascii representation of the hex string to a binary file, if I use System.Text.Encoding.ASCII as follows: writeBinay.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hdStr)); when I view the written file in a hex editor it looks like this: 31 36 33 34 32 44 31 46 34 41 36 31 42 43 (16342D1F4A61BC)

Comment: Ah - you want to write out the hex for the string rather than the ASCII bytes.  OK.

Answer (score 0):

How important is endian-ness to you in the file?

Perhaps you can use something like:

```
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToUInt32(hdStr, 16));
```